# MySQL high CPU usage while processlist is empty

Tags: mysql, linux, cpu-usage

Our CPU usage is through the roof. It's ranging from 10-150%. We noticed this few weeks ago and it is still not going down.

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

Shows only 2-3 sleeping connections and my own SHOW PROCESSLIST query.

```
mysqladmin -u root -p -i 1 processlist
```

Shows pretty much the same thing with an occassional query here and there.

```
sudo strace -t -p 18691
```

Keeps printing this over and over again every second or so with only few integers changing:

```
10:50:39 fcntl(13, F_GETFL)             = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
10:50:39 fcntl(13, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
10:50:39 accept(13, {sa_family=AF_FILE, NULL}, [2]) = 28
10:50:39 fcntl(13, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)     = 0
10:50:39 getsockname(28, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"}, [30]) = 0
10:50:39 fcntl(28, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY)   = 0
10:50:39 fcntl(28, F_GETFL)             = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
10:50:39 setsockopt(28, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\36\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 0
10:50:39 setsockopt(28, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, "<\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 0
10:50:39 fcntl(28, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
10:50:39 setsockopt(28, SOL_IP, IP_TOS, [8], 4) = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported)
10:50:39 futex(0x7f4175a0ed24, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x7f4175a0ed20, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
10:50:39 futex(0x7f4175a0d7a0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
10:50:39 poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLIN}])
10:50:39 fcntl(13, F_GETFL)             = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
10:50:39 fcntl(13, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
10:50:39 accept(13, {sa_family=AF_FILE, NULL}, [2]) = 43
10:50:39 fcntl(13, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)     = 0
10:50:39 getsockname(43, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"}, [30]) = 0
```

And I have no idea how to analyze that. Can you spot anything wrong with the strace?

The kernel version is 3.13.0-44-generic so I assume this should not be the leap second bug? Is there a way I can check if our machine suffers from the leap second bug?